# Plotting with RegionFunction without explicit function variables

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

Before updating Mathematica license to version 12, I was able to exclude regions of plots (in `Plot`, `Plot3D`, `DensityPlot`) with RegionFunction without needing the condition to explicitly display its dependence to the variables. Now I get the following error message: "Function [...] must be a Boolean function".

As an example, I plot the following exponential function:
`Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 3}}]`

[image]

I want to exclude points according to a function of `x` that is different from `Exp[x]`, for example `x^2`:

[image]

I used to write it:

```
functest = x^2;
Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 3}}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, functest < 0.5]]
```

But if I do so now, I get the error message and it does not exclude any points.

It works if I define the function `functest` with its argument:

```
functest[x_] := x^2;
Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 3}}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, functest[x] < 0.5]]
```

My problem is that `functest` in my code is typically a long analytical expression (for example the solutions of a system of differential equations) and I would like to find a way to call it without having to define it explicitly with respect to its variables.

Comment: Looks like an evaluation leak that was fixed. Use `Function[{x, y}, Evaluate[functest < .5]]` instead.

Comment: Awesome it works!